# Page_Load not executed if web page accessed directly by URL (Default.aspx)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm having a very odd problem with a legacy asp.net webforms application.
I'm developing a very simple user tracking method, and I need to call a single subroutine in the page load, if a querystring param is equal to something.
For example:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Request.QueryString("rf") = "dem" Then
        TrackUser();
    End If

End Sub
```

The absurd thing is that if I load the web site through www.mydomain.com/Default.aspx?rf=dem, TrackUser() is called.
Instead, if I load www.mydomain.com/?rf=dem, TrackUser() isn't called.

I thought it was a problem regarding the querystring, so I wrote something like:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Response.Write("Test page_load")
        If Request.QueryString("rf") = "dem" Then
            TrackUser();
        End If

    End Sub
```

And "Test page_load" is NOT written if I reach the website through www.mydomain.com.
How come?

Comment: Does break point hit if you set at `If Request...`?

Comment: Is `default.aspx` the default page of your site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly, I re-deployed once again, and now it works. I think the issue with the cache has to do with the application pool that had not correctly "recycled" the cache when I first removed the "Outputcache tag", in the first deploy.
Thanks for the replies, however; and sorry for the useless question.

Answer (score 2):

You may have output caching turned on somewhere that causes the page to be returned from a previously-built string.

Comment: I had on that page the OutputCache flag for Default.aspx; and I already removed it and re-deployed the website. But nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put this code inside of Global.asax's `Application_BeginRequest` event?

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(Byval sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    ' Fires at the beginning of each request

    If Request.QueryString("rf") = "dem" Then 
        TrackUser()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I need to track only three pages in particular. Putting it into Global.asax doesn't slow down the entire website?

Comment: Why would you do it at the page level anyway?  If you are going to do that, at least create a base page that your pages inherit from so that the tracking is all in one place.  But for this, `Application_BeginRequest` is specifically for code you want to run before each page request starts.  It's the perfect place for tracking.

Comment: I think it's the best solution, in fact just now I'm thinking of expanding the tracking to more than three-four pages; and handling it in the beginrequest method is way more reliable instead of manual editing of every page. Thanks for advice!